# Should 屋 and 居 use radical 户 instead of 尸?

Tags: meaning, characters, etymology, radicals, glyph-origin

户 means home. So these examples are not suprising: 房 fáng (house),  扁 biǎn (flat), 扇 shàn (fan [mostly used indoor]), 扉 fēi (door)

尸 means corpse, and it looks like it refers to tail or something leaving downwards, so these examples are not suprising either:
尿 niào (urine), 尾 wěi (tail), 屎 shǐ (poo), 屁 pì (fart)

However, 屋 wū (room) and 居 jū (live) under 尸 is suprising since it seems to belong more to 户 by its meaning.

Is this discrepancy above due to a calligraphical mistake or lazyness, namely, leaving off that one tick, made a long time ago?

sources:

http://justlearnchinese.com/chinese-radical-show-home-radical-42/

http://justlearnchinese.com/chinese-radical-show-corpse-radical-41/

Comment: 尸 was 屍 before simplification, where death is stressed in 死 not 尸 itself.

Comment: It's a very interesting question that , as I am a Chinese, never occurred to me.  Thanks for asking from a different perspective.

Answer (score 12):

> Is this discrepancy above due to a calligraphical mistake or lazyness, namely, leaving off that one tick, made a long time ago?

**TL;DR:** I don't think so, because (1) `尸` used as the pictographic radical with the meaning `house` in `屋` was explicitly mentioned in 说文解字 long before, (2) the original meanings of `尸` and `户` used as radicals are not exactly the same (`house` vs `single door`).

#### 1. About `尸` (and `屋`)

`尸` used as the pictograph in [`屋`](http://www.zdic.net/z/18/xs/5C4B.htm) was explicitly mentioned in [说文解字](http://www.zdic.net/z/18/sw/5C4B.htm):

> 居也。从尸。尸，所主也。一曰尸，象屋形。(*`尸` looks like house.*)
>
> 会意。从尸,从至。尸,与房屋有关,“至”表示来到。人来到这里居住之意。

[This article](http://www.guokr.com/question/559701/) summarized three usages of `尸` when used as radical.

(*italics is translation from me*)

> A.从原意而来，代表人的躯体。(*Derived from the original meaning, represents body of human.*)
>
> ```
> 会意字有：
> 屍：死去的躯体，就是尸体。屍和尸古来就一直通用。
> 尿：躯体排出的水分。
> 屎：米经过躯体排出来的东西。
> 屄：躯干上的洞。
> 尾：躯干后面的毛。
> 等等。
>
> 形声字有：
> 尻，屌，屈，屑，屙，屁
> 属（声旁是蜀，不是禹），
> 届（声旁是凷，不是由），含义是到达，比如届时，无远弗届等等。
> 展，屠，
> 尼：原意为靠近，后来用昵字代替了本意。至于尼姑的尼，则是梵语比丘尼（bhikṣunī）的音译缩略。
> 居：原意为蹲下。后来用踞字代替了本意。
> 等等。
> ```
>
> B. 从履字来的，表示各种鞋子的字。履不是人体的部位，但是是服装，所以和尸的原意仍然有关联。(*Derived from 履, used to represent various kinds of shoes. 履 is not the part of body, but the clothing, it's still relevant to the original meaning of 尸.*)
>
> ```
> 这类字有：
> 屐：木鞋
> 屝：泛指鞋
> 屜：鞋子里垫的草。
> 屟（屧）：鞋子的木底
> 屣：鞋子
> 屦：麻鞋
> 等等
> ```
>
> C.第三类的尸本意不是躯体，而是指房屋。其形状像一面墙壁和屋顶。(*The meaning of the 3rd kind of 尸 is not body, but the house. Its shape looks like a wall and the roof.*)
>
> ```
> 这类字有：
> 屋，
> 层（層）：原意指楼（重屋），引申为重，重复。
> 屏：原意指影壁墙。
> ```

#### 2. About `户` (and `房`)

[`户`](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/xs/6237.htm) means single leaf door originally, note it's not exactly the same but relevant to `house`.

> 象形。甲骨文字形,象门(門)字的一半。汉字部首之一。从“户”的多与门户有关。本义:单扇门

Here's a picture from the book "字源谈趣" explaining the difference between `门` and `户`, especially their ancient form (left-most one).

[image]

Now we could understand the original meaning of [`房`](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/xs/623F.htm), i.e. `正室左右的住室` (*wing room/side room (with single door)*)

> 上古边室皆用单扇门(即“户”),庙门大门才用双扇门,故“房”从“户”。本义:正室左右的住室

#### Additional information about `居`

[`居`](http://www.zdic.net/z/18/xs/5C45.htm) seems to be the different case with `屋`.

> 象形。金文字形,是“踞”的本字,象人曲胫蹲踞形。本义:蹲着

`居` is the original character of `踞`, means `squat`. Then it was used for other meanings, `踞` was created for the using of the meaning `squat`. So the usage of `尸` in `居` should be the 1st case shown as before.

Answer (score 3):

No, they shouldn't; this is a misunderstanding of what the components in those characters came from.

---

「尸」does not mean *corpse*; it is a picture of a squatting person, and is used as a component representing a person's physical body in other characters.

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[鐵](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)35.2
[合集20643](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=20643&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)112
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

- 「尿」was originally a picture of someone urinating.

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [菁](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)5.1
  [合集137](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=137&jgwfl=)</kbd>
- 「尾」was originally a picture of a person and the shape of a tail at the backside.

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)4293
  [合集136](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=136&jgwfl=)</kbd>
- 「屎」was originally a picture of someone defecating in a field.

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [後](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.35.7
  [合集9574](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=9574&jgwfl=)</kbd>
- 「屁」contains phonetic「比」.
- 「居」(*residence/dwelling*, Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*k(r)a/**, **/*ka/**, **/*k(r)a-s/**) contains

  - semantic「尸」(*body*)
  - phonetic「古」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*kˤaʔ/**)

---

「屋」(*building*/*room*/*house*) did not contain「尸」!「屋」was a picture of a tent, and this word is now written as「幄」.

<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
說文古文</kbd>

In「屋」,「至」was missing in earlier forms and later added on; it is an abbreviation of「室」(also *room*/*house*) functioning as a semantic component.

The tent shape was later subject to gradual corruption into「尸」.

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
訓匜「」
[集成10285](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10285)</kbd>
<kbd>篆
[image]
說文[籀文](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shizhoupian)</kbd>
　<kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 2):

The character 尸 actually represents a sitting person while acting as a component.

The character 居 is 尸 + 古 (a baby 子turned upside down: ）, the place where women sit down and have children: settlement.

The character 屋 is 尸 + 至 (arriving: an arrow landing in the hround), the place where people arrive and sit down: house, residence.